# Django-Filter "contains" on related field

Tags: django, django-filter

I have two simple models which are linked by a Foreign Key:

```
models.py:
class Operator(models.Model):
    operator = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, verbose_name='Operator')
    operator_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Operator Name', blank=False, null=False)

class SubOperator(models.Model):
    operator = models.ForeignKey(Operator, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_operator = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Sub Operator')
    sub_operator_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Start Date')
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='End Date')
```

The User should be able to select the operator with a "like" which translates to "lookup_expr='contains'" in the Django-Filter Module but unfortunately I get the following Exception:
"django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: contains"

```
filters.py:
operator = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='operator', lookup_expr='contains', label='Operator')
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your `field_name` argument to ***`operator__operator_name`*** instead of `operator`

```
operator = django_filters.CharFilter(
    field_name='operator__operator_name',
    lookup_expr='contains',
    label='Operator'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution (the documentation is a little bit misleading on how to properly write the lookup expression from my perspective, but maybe thats only me^^)

The correct way to write this is:

```
operator = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='operator', lookup_expr='operator__contains', label='Operator')
```

So more or less if you take your standard filter object and check what options it gives you for the field, thats what you can put into the lookup_expr of django filter!